# Perl script is returning incorrect output of zombie process on Linux box

Tags: perl

Perl script is returning incorrect value of zomibie process on Linux box

```
    my $threshold = 5;

    $number_of_defuncts = `ps -ef | grep defunct |grep -v grep|wc -l`;
    if ( $number_of_defuncts > $threshold )
    {
            print("number of defunct is [$number_of_defuncts] \n");
    }
```

WHen manually checked via ps command then zombie processes are always zero but using perl script is giving the erroneous output of 7, 8 or similar high number.

Comment: Tip: To avoid `grep` finding itself use `grep "[d]efunct"` instead, one of [several approaches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results) to avoid the secondary `grep -v`.

Comment: It's hard to know without more system/code context.  Can you please show us the output of `ps -ef | grep de[f]unct | wc -l` and then the output of `perl -E 'say \`ps -ef | grep de[f]unct | wc -l\`'` from the same shell's prompt?

Answer (score 2):

(linux only)

```
$zombie_count = do { local *ARGV; @ARGV=</proc/[0-9]*/stat>; grep /Z[^)]*$/, <> }
```

Just grepping for `defunct` in the `ps` output is broken, because a process may put `defunct` in its command line just to break your script. More robust (but yet not portable [1]) solutions are `ps -eo state | grep Z` or `ps -eo s | grep Z`.

In your case, your perl script is probably creating the extra zombies, which disappear when it terminates. Unlike the shell, perl will not greedily reap its children as soon as they die; it's up to you to `wait()` for them, either directly or indirectly:

```
$ perl -e 'my $pid = open my $fh, "echo yup|"; exec "ps", $pid'
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
 6840 pts/11   Z+     0:00 [echo] <defunct>
$ perl -e 'my $pid = open my $fh, "echo yup|"; undef $fh; exec "ps", $pid'
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
$ perl -e 'my $pid = open my $fh, "echo yup|"; wait; exec "ps", $pid'
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
$ perl -e 'my $pid = open FH, "echo yup|"; close FH; exec "ps", $pid'
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
```

[1] no, `ps -ef` is not portable, either.